# Design UI in android by using relative and linear - text and clickable images

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, textview, clickable

I am tried to design UI as shown below image. Here  I want to design two textViews and three imageViews as shown here.

[image]

I tried this but after passing data to textViews dynamically it showing wrongly (overriding one text on another text)

This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="90dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

    <!-- ListRow Left side navigation_image image -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:padding="3dip" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_marker_image_view"
            android:layout_width="30dip"
            android:layout_height="30dip"
            android:contentDescription="@string/navigation_image"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:src="@drawable/navigation_marker" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/share_image_view"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/date_time_text_view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigation_image"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_time_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address_text_view"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="sans" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/share_image_view"
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/favourite_image_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/favourite_image_view"
        android:contentDescription="@string/share_image"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/share" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/edit_image_view"
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address_text_view"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/edit_buttonon_image"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/edit" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/favourite_image_view"
        android:layout_width="25dip"
        android:layout_height="25dip"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_image_view"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_image_view"
        android:contentDescription="@string/favarouite_image"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/favourite" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to get corrrect design as shown above, which should work properly.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `TextView` issues are arising from that 90dip height, the RelativeLayout is trying to put everything in there but doesn't have enough space and is ending up overlaying views.

Changing it to `wrap_content` should fix it. Unless you absolutely know that a fixed is going to big enough, don't use one.

Of course the above will cause the `ImageView`s to be pushed to the bottom, so remove from the `edit_image_view`

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and adding this to the `edit_image_view`

```
android:layout_below="@+id/address_text_view"
```

but then you'll need to remove this from `address_text_view` to avoid the circular dependency

```
android:layout_above="@+id/share_image_view"
```

edit for clarity

Your relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="90dip"   <-- change to wrap_content
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

<!-- ListRow Left side navigation_image image -->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigation_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:padding="3dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_marker_image_view"
        android:layout_width="30dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/navigation_image"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:src="@drawable/navigation_marker" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/share_image_view" <-- remove this
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date_time_text_view"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigation_image"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_time_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/share_image_view"
    android:layout_width="25dip"
    android:layout_height="25dip"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/favourite_image_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/favourite_image_view"
    android:contentDescription="@string/share_image"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/share" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/edit_image_view"
    android:layout_width="25dip"
    android:layout_height="25dip"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" <-- remove this
    android:layout_below="@+id/address_text_view"  <-- add this
    android:layout_marginLeft="29dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/edit_buttonon_image"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/edit" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/favourite_image_view"
    android:layout_width="25dip"
    android:layout_height="25dip"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/edit_image_view"
    android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_image_view"
    android:contentDescription="@string/favarouite_image"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:src="@drawable/favourite" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Getting this class cast exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

Comment: class cast was probably caused by you changing one of the image views ids to whatever the textview was, i'll edit my answer to be clearer

Comment: Hey.. thanks its perfect what I want exactly it is..Thank you very much.. :)

Comment: can I put one image view on another image. Here I need to replace focused image when click on normal image. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

this UI is correct but you have to fix the textviews size to avoid overlapping of text:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/share_image_view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/date_time_text_view"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/navigation_image"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/date_time_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/address_text_view"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />
```

Comment: Sorry, not working then here also showing at here and there not in a proper way as shown in graphical layout